# Make substitution reference on strong containing equals sign

Tags: string, makefile, escaping

I'm trying to use a [Make substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs) to alter a string.   The problem being that the string happens to contain an equals `=` symbol.

For example:

```
INPUT = -switch1 -switch2=potato -switch3
OUTPUT = $(INPUT:-switch2=%=-switch2=turnip)

all:
    @echo TEST : $(OUTPUT)
```

so in the form `$(var:a=b)`, `INPUT` is var, `-switch2=%` is `a` and `-switch2=turnip` is `b`.

Obviously that doesn't work because `=` is a special character in this context, but I've no idea how to make it realize that this is part of string `a`.
I've tried quoting, backslashes, alternative escape characters and putting `-switch2=%` in a variable and using that instead.   All to no avail.

I know I can use patsubst, but that'd be adding the first non-POSIX extension to the file and i'd prefer to not be that guy.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a full `patsubst` function.  Substitution references are just a shortcut for `patsubst`:

```
OUTPUT = $(patsubst -switch2=%,-switch2=turnip,$(INPUT))
```

Comment: Thanks, although I was keen to avoid using `patsubstr`, as I believe it's a gnu extension (so things like automake will warn on its usage).